# How to put image and text into tooltip?

Tags: html, css, web

I want to put tooltip into an image that will display a small will screen with img, text, and able use HTML, CSS 
I use boostrap and have no ideal what to do next :<

Something like this:
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1zTB.png)

This just part of the code.

```
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 align-content-center">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h3 class="text-uppercase">Team of 2018-2019</h3>
                    </div> 
                <div class="team-memberpre">
                      <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle" src="...image...">
                      <h4>...name....</h4>
                  <p class="text-muted">President</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="team-member">
                  <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle" src="..image.." alt="">
                  <h5>...name....</h5>
                  <p class="text-muted">Lead Marketing</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank, I will try, but at first I tried to use tooltip tag but popover is a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chaudigv/07cxkdLt/3/) exmaple

You can achieve image + text with popover with `data-html="true"` and `data-content="html code"`

your .html code

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-content='<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://www.anime-planet.com/images/anime/covers/naruto-22.jpg" width=60 height=60 />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <b>some</b> text here
    </div>
  </div>'>
  Popover on with image and text
</button>
</div>
```

.js file

```
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```